# Rewrite rules conflicting with existent files

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I came across some htaccess url rewrite rules which are conflicting to existing url.

1. To write my category pages to www.mydomain.com/categoryname.html

   I'm using following rule which is working fine but all my other pages like www.mydomain.com/about.html shows 404 not found

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /category_parent.php?ctg=$1 [L]
   ```
2. To write my product pages like www.mydomain.com/25/productname.html

   I'm using following code which is also working fine

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /product.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L]
   ```

   but the above rewrite rule conflicting with sub category pages for which I'm using following code:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /category_child.php?pctg=$1&ctg=$2 [L]
   ```

In brief, I want to write to,

```
www.mydomain.com/categoryname.html

www.mydomain.com/categoryname/subcategoryname.html

www.mydomain.com/25/productname.html
```

But Some rules messing with each other. I'll appreciate if you can provide me little clue on this.

Comment: Enable the *Rewrite Log*. Show what rewrites are happening by presenting the *Rewrite Log* s content. Also show the 404 from the *Error Log*.

Comment: And if you want to have an easy rewrite, rewrite all non-existant files/folders to a single PHP page and inside that PHP page parse the request URL and delegate to the right script (frontend-controller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files are colliding the non-existent to existent ones, you should use a condition to verify if a file, directory or symbolic link exists.

For files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

For folders:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

For symbolic links:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

The exclamation mark `!` is used to negate their meaning `!-f` means if the file does not exist then apply rule if it exists then do not apply rule.

Keep in mind that a `RewriteCond` should be followed by a `RewriteRule` and you can have one or more conditions per `RewriteRule`, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /category_parent.php?ctg=$1 [L]
```

In this case it means if directory does not exist and file does not exist and symbolic link does not exist then we redirect but if any of the previous condition exist then we don't redirect.

Comment: prix, thanks for the reply, as I already told the htaccess codes I've given are working fine only conflicting with others. Like I used your code for www.mydomain.com/categoryname.html which is also working fine but for www.mydomain.com/about.html I'm getting 404 not found.

Comment: @prototype does the page about.html exists or should it go else where ?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` by using this condition if a file exists the rule will not rewrite it.

Comment: @Prix: No, it does not have. Otherwise same would apply for `\w`, too. - http://pcre.org/pcre.txt - search `any "word" character` in the following it's written which ones qualify and when.

Comment: only if you have got unicode mode endabled. do you have (also checkout URI specs which are US-ASCII based)?

Comment: @Prix yes about.html exits, if I delete this url rewrite code form htaccess, it works fine. I'm pretty sute category url rewrite code conflicting with it

Comment: @Prix, Man it worked. I appreciate. Thanks a lot dear friend. I was literally pulling my hair off, LOL, let me select it as best answer. thanks again :-)